# Display Heirarchial Tree ASP C# / Stringbuilder / Recursion

Tags: c#, recursion, tree, hierarchy, stringbuilder

I've done some searching around and quite find anything that's similar to my scenario, and would appreciate another pair of eyes to give me some advice.

I've been tasked with displaying a tree of data, and have the stored procedure worked out that creates this table structure:
[image]

It should contain everything I need, including level, parent and folder id [document_category_id]

The plan is to display the data using the following HTML structure

```
<div class="parent">Folder 1</div>
    <div class="sublevel">
        <div class="subfolder">Folder 1 Subfolder</div>
             <div class="sublevel">
                 <div class="subfolder">Folder 1 Subfolder Level 2</div>
              </div>

<div class="parent">Folder 2</div>
    <div class="sublevel">
        <div class="subfolder">Subfolder 1</div>
        <div class="subfolder">Subfolder 2</div>
    </div>
```

The sublevel class has a margin which creates indentation, and subsequent child node insertions increase the identation.

Here's the C# code. Admittedly, I haven't had much experience with recursion and I'm interested to learn how to solve this. I modeled this lightly after this post: [non-normalized heirarchy / stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783337/how-do-i-display-non-normalized-data-in-a-hierarchical-structure) but you'll see there are some differences

```
SqlConnection connection = null;
        connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationData.databaseConnectionString);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("myconnectionstring", connection);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myparameter", myparameter);

        try {
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            int rowcount = 0;
            int count = reader.FieldCount;

            while (reader.Read()) {

                _folderCategoryId = (int)reader["document_category_id"];
                if (!DBNull.Value.Equals(reader["parent_category_id"])) {
                    _folderParentCategoryId = (int)reader["parent_category_id"];
                }
                if (DBNull.Value.Equals(reader["parent_category_id"])) {
                    _folderParentCategoryId = 0;
                }
                _level = (int)reader["level"];
                _folderName = (string)reader["name"];
                _folderDescription = (string)reader["description"];
                rowcount = rowcount + 1;
                //parent catgories get their own closed "parent" class div


                if (_level == 0) {
                    _displayString.Append("<div class=\"parent\" >");
                    _displayString.Append(_folderName);
                    _displayString.Append("</div>");
                }

                for (int i = 1; i <= _level; i++) {
                    WriteNode(reader, _displayString);
                }
                _displayString.Append("</div>");

            }
            if (rowcount < 1) {
                _displayString.Clear();
                _displayString.Append("No Folders");
            }
        }
        catch {
            _displayString.Clear();
            _displayString.Append("Error Retreiving Documents List");
        }
            finally {
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
    }
    // recursively write out each node
    public static void WriteNode(SqlDataReader reader, StringBuilder _displayString) {


        // find children rows...
        int level = (int)reader["level"];
        string name = (string)reader["name"];


        if (level >= 1) {
            _displayString.Append("</div>");
            _displayString.Append("<div class=\"sublevel\">");
            _displayString.Append(name);

        }

    }
```

So, I know there's stuff wrong here obviously. I've been mangling it and it kinda works but is mostly unreliable There are usually unclosed divs, or too many closing div tags depending on the number of children.

Most likely its the call to the WriteNode method - should I be checking previous folderid values here? Is length good enough? Should I be closing a div in here?

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out a few days ago. Recursion is not necessary with the dataset that I used.

```
if (_level > prevLevel) { //must be a child
                        _displayString.Append("<div class=");
                        _displayString.Append("\"subfolder\" >");
                        formatClickString(_displayString, _folderCategoryId, _uploadVisibility, _folderName);
                    }
                if (_level < prevLevel) { //start new level
                        for (int i = 0; i <= prevLevel; i++) {
                            _displayString.Append("</div>");
                        }
                    _displayString.Append("<div class=\"subfolder\" >");
                    formatClickString(_displayString, _folderCategoryId, _uploadVisibility, _folderName);

                    }
                if (_level == prevLevel) { //is child and own line
                    _displayString.Append("</div>");
                    _displayString.Append("<div class=\"subfolder\" >");
                    formatClickString(_displayString, _folderCategoryId, _uploadVisibility, _folderName);

                    }
                prevLevel = _level;
```

Hopefully this will come in handy in the event someone else needs to build a tree.